# How do I include Boost libraries?

Tags: c++, boost, include, boost-geometry

I'm trying to incorporate the Boost libraries into my program, specifically `lexical_cast` and `geometry`. I include them using `#include"boost/boost/geometry.hpp"` and `#include"boost/boost/lexical_cast/lexical_cast_old.hpp"`.

When I run the code I get the fatal error "Cannot open include file: 'boost/geometry/geometry.hpp': No such file or directory" which leads me to another .hpp file in the Boost library which includes another library, but uses `#include<...>` instead of `#include"..."`.

When I replace it for `"..."` the error for this one goes, but it is replaced with the next library included using `#include<...>` instead of `#include"..."`.

I feel like this could lead me down a rabbit hole of replacing nearly all instances of `#include<...>` with `#include"..."` which would take ages. Is there a setting I can change or a piece of code I could include that would sort this out?

Or could I just get rid of all the other unnecessary libraries and change the ones I need (I know that, that would still be a lot as they seem to rely on each other).

I have Boost library version 1.58.0.

Comment: You need to pass the compiler the include directories. Which compiler do you use?

Comment: instead of `boost/boost/`*filename* you should have `boost/`*filename*. Adjust your compiler's include path accordingly. Also use angle brackets for the include.

Comment: I'm not sure, how do I find out? I'm using visual studios 2012 and writing in C++

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf when I use angled brackets to include the lexical_cast for example an error appearers on the `#include` saying cannot open the source file "...". How do I adjust my compiler's include path?

Comment: @Peter: it depends on the compiler. many compilers accept an `-I` (uppercase) followed by directory path, as command line option. with g++ you can specify paths in `CPATH` environment variable, which then is treated as a last `-I` option. correspondingly with Visual C++ you can use the `INCLUDE` environment variable.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First you should read about the difference between `#include "filepath"` and `#include <filepath>` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename).

Personally, I'm working with Boost from Visual Studio as follows:

1. Go to *Project properties* → *C/C++* → *General* → *Additional Include Directories*, and add a path to the `boost` library root (in my case `C:\Program Files (x86)\Boost_1_53`).
2. Include a .hpp file in your sources, like `#include <boost/lexical_cast/lexical_cast_old.hpp>`

If you're using non headers-only libraries you should also add path to Boost libraries in *Project properties* → *Linker* → *General* → *Additional Libraries Directories*.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2012, right-click on your project and select "Properties".

In the properties dialog, select "Configuration Properties" and then "VC++ Directories".

You will need to add the Boost include path to the "Include Directories" list.

If you're using all header-only libraries then you're done. Otherwise, you will need to add the Boost library path to "Library Directories".

Answer (score 1):

For example:

1. Boost library - `c:\boost\boost_1_58_0` (run `booststrap.bat` and `b2` as administrator).
2. Add strings `$(THIRD_PARTY)\boost\boost_1_58_0\include` and `$(THIRD_PARTY)\boost\boost_1_58_0\` to *VC++ Directories* → *Include Directories*

Comment: Unfortunately after running the build steps I have no include folder !?